# xpath and html value (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, xpath

Let's say I want to check if "xpath html value" is equal to some text in a website.

Like:

```
html/body/div/div[7]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td value = "some text"
```

How do I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `document.evaluate` to do this:

```
var value = document.evaluate('html/body/div/div[7]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td', document.documentElement, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.textContent;
```

Have a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript#Specifying_the_Return_Type) for some more information on how to set up an iterator and iterate through a number of nodes, in case you need to get the value of more than just one `td` in the `tr`.

Answer (score -1):

You may want to try [jQuery XPath plugin with support for XPath 2.0](https://github.com/ilinsky/jquery-xpath) syntax that works cross-browser.

Code you would write:

```
var found = $(document).xpath("html/body/div/div[7]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/text()") == "some text";
```